# Do Hessian-based optimizers benefit from preconditioners?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

From what I understand, preconditioners are a way to encode prior knowledge of the shape of the objective landscape to make it appear more circular (and thereby easier for a first-order method to solve).

Do second-order optimization methods benefit from preconditioners? I think that they don't given that they infer a local quadratic model. (And thereby don't need this additional information)

My follow up question: are there any trade-offs between using a preconditioner versus using a Hessian? They both seem to try to solve the same issue -- trying to get local curvature (one uses domain knowledge and the other computes this information).

Comment: Preconditioners are typically used in _Hessian-free_ methods. And the reason the methods are Hessian free is usually because constructing the Hessian would be prohibitively expensive. So there is certainly a tradeoff, but maybe not the one you're asking about?

Comment: I think that makes sense to me. Preconditioners save us compute by avoiding the expensive costs associated with computing the Hessian -- they do this by incorporating domain knowledge from the modeller (the modeller must provide information about the nature of the curvature). 

In essence, I think these preconditioning methods are implicitly computing a Hessian by making some assumptions about what it might look like. Would that be a correct statement?

Comment: Also higher order derivatives than second order can behave rapidly which would cause the Hessian to not contain valid information about where to go in more than in some quite localized region.

Answer (score 3):

Scaling an unconstrained problem does not affect Hessian-based optimizers. Any monotone linear transformations does not affect the Newton direction ($\nabla^2f\Delta x=-\nabla f$ and $A\nabla^2f\Delta x=-A\nabla f$ have the same solution). Scaling can help to solve poorly scaled problems with finite precision arithmetic.

In constrained optimization, interior point methods rely on the Hessian. For those, relative scaling of variables and scaling constraints does affect the course of the algorithm.

Comment: Interesting. Many methods are based around the Hessian. It feels so arbitrary. It's a local quadratic model. Why not anything else?

Comment: It is not arbitrary. An optimization problem with a convex quadratic objective and linear equality constraints can be solved in one step.

Comment: And the logic behind that -- is in the real world, there exists a lot of quadratic objective functions?

Comment: The logic is in the math. The KKT conditions for such an optimization problem are linear equations.

Comment: Thanks for the resp; KKT conditions are conditions for first order methods to converge. I don't know how that answers my question.

Comment: @echo KKT conditions are way more than that. Local quadratic models are popular because the KKT conditions for such optimization models are linear equations. That means that such a local model can be minimized by solving a system of linear equations.

Comment: I'm re-reading on those conditions now. But the only appealing property that you are arguing is computational efficiency. If the KKT tells us that we can solve a quadratic with a system of linear equations -- that only tells me we're saving compute time. Quadratic methods are not appealing in terms of getting a better solution quality.

Comment: You are deviation much from your initial question, but I do not understand your comment "Quadratic methods are not appealing in terms of getting a better solution quality." For convex problems, quadratic methods are the fastest and most reliable algorithms. They find the optimal solution, so there is no "getting a better solution quality".

Comment: I appreciate that you're still tolerating my questions. If we took the cubic direction instead of the quadratic (Newton) direction. We'd get much  better performance.

Comment: Are you sure? Can you give an example?

Comment: Definitionally so. If we had a cubic model of the local neighbourhood instead of a quadratic model of the local neighbourhood, a cubic model is obviously more precise.

Comment: Quadratic models result in locally quadratic convergence near the optimal solution. Do you have a similar result for cubic models? How do you optimize your cubic model in dimensions higher than 1?

Comment: I'm trying to argue that taking the cubic direction would give us much better results. The actual optimization procedure can be obtained by continuing the Taylor series expansion. The cubic direction implies taking a curvature matrix with the third derivative, which is typically infeasible. But if obtaining the cubic direction were possible, it would be much more accurate than the Newton direction.